# It is possible to do a autonumber sequence in a SELECT on Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sequence

I need to do a task in Oracle that I don't know how can I possible do this.

Ok, I need to do a SELECT when I define a autonumber sequence on-the-fly.

For example:

```
Select autonumber(1, 9000) as auto from some_table
```

And the result would be

```
auto
------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
...
9000
```

This would be possible to do? Are there any oracle build in function that will help me doing this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
select 
  rownum
from 
  dba_objects, 
  dba_objects
where
  rownum <= 9000;
```

Comment: dirty dirty hack. use 'dual' table like in the top voted answer

Answer (score 20):

If you want a sequence of numbers independent of rows in an actual table, rather than numbering the returned rows (in which case look at `rownum` or `row_number()`), you can do:

```
select level as auto
from dual
connect by level <= 9000;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Oracle's built in rownum

```
select rownum as auto, other1, other2 from some_table
```

For ANSI compliance, you can use ROW_NUMBER() for later versions of Oracle